# How to get one value from a method in class without recalculating?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I am wondering if I can get a value from a method which does not belong to object, and use it in another method under the same class.

Here is a sample code:

```
class Additon:
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number=number

    def arithmetic(self,k):
        newnumber1=self.number+k
        newnumber2 = self.number-k

        return [newnumber1,newnumber2]

    def add(self):
        a=self.arithmetic(1)
        return a[0]

    def minus(self):
        #get new number2
```

I would like to get `newnumber2` in `minus` method without calling `arithmetic` again. This is just a sample code for my programming assignment, the result does not matter. I would like to know the way of doing this.

Comment: Yes, save the value of `self.arithmetic(1)` somewhere, perhaps as an attribute.

Comment: self.newnumber2 = self.number-k... def minus(self): return self.newnumber2

Comment: where do i put this code? @user3713719

Comment: how do i do this? @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: @Robin `self.myattribute = some_object` generally speaking. It's up to you where you think it would go best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Additon:
    def __init__(self,number):
        self.number=number

    def arithmetic(self,k):
        newnumber1=self.number+k
        self.newnumber2 = self.number-k

        return [newnumber1,newnumber2]

    def add(self):
        a=self.arithmetic(1)
        return a[0]

    def minus(self):
        return self.newnumber2
```